# Mine Chat Room when I First open

Tags: support, chat

When I click on mine tab the chat room do not appear
knowing that I'm in 2 chat rooms
any ideas why they are not showing?

How can I filter rooms with the ones I'm in?

Comment: Have you opened the **mine** in another tab before entering the chatrooms?

Comment: When I first open the site and want goto m]the chat room. I click mine they are not there so i goto all and filter by name and when I type there and then goto mine its there. The question is why its not there first time I opened it???

Comment: @MohammadMMohammad if we detect that you aren't in the room (your browser isn't responding etc), then *we evict you*; so : a while after closing the browser *you aren't in the room anymore*. Hence when you come back to that tab, it will show as empty. As Anamika notes, using "favorites" is a better idea here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mine chat room means the chat rooms **you are currently in**.

So when you go to the site first time, it will be empty as you haven't entered any room yet.

If you want to keep some room in your preferences, use favorite. Notice a star on any room. Click on it, so it will be added to your favorite room.

> [image]

Now when you will go to the site next time, go to favorites tab shown below.

So you will be able to see your preferred rooms.

> [image]

Hope you got the meaning of 'Mine' rooms now.

Comment: As a hidden extra, the "rejoin all" button has a href (not used normally) that can be bookmarked for convenience: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/chats/join/favorite - note that for idempotent reasons, we only *actually* join the rooms if it is a POST not a GET, but we can at least make is easy by showing a single button

Comment: Ok.. @MarcGravell Was aware about rejoin all, but not actual functionality behind that. Thanks for sharing :)